# Using a Python Script in My Hype 3 Build

Tags: python, python-3.x, html

I have a Python script that I would like to run in my Hype 3 build. The script takes an input (several) and outputs an answer based on on the input (but that’s handled in the script) how I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

Tumult Hype’s Export Scripts infrastructure allows code to be run upon export and/or preview. This can be python code, in fact the sample scripts we have are all in Python.

General info: https://tumult.com/hype/export-scripts/
Developer docs & code: https://github.com/tumult/hype-export-scripts/

With this, you can arbitrarily modify Hype’s output however you see fit.

You’ll get a new File > Export as HTML5 > … menu item; this allows choosing a location to save. I don’t think there’s any way to bypass the save dialog at this point. You probably just ignore it. (Though I guess you could also be clever and have a Preview stick your document wherever you want, since previewing doesn’t have a prompt).